# 404 Error after site collection creation

Tags: 404

I have create my own solution and I manage to deploy it in server.
But when I create new site collection, I get 404 Error message. 
"The webpage cannot be found".
I can create team site and I can access it. So, problem must be in this project.

But I'm not sure what cause this problem. Is it master page or page or what?
(I'm not sure that have I understand Elements.xml files right.)
If someone guru/superman/pro can check my solution and tell me what cause this problem.
I would be grateful =)

You can download whole project here:
https://mega.co.nz/#!VwMVgLYI!FZ1C3mZta0R6aNnSnEEKq2lCbBpng_yhJqt_6vhUr0c

Here is just log file:
https://mega.co.nz/#!Zh8BDDLC!NJOpODIwmeijILFuATRh21W-r6gjo11Zqb_hzn6wK4A

Comment: I have no intentions of downloading your whole project, so I will ask you: Do you have your custom WebTemplate? Do you in this activate a feature that will provision a default page?

Comment: Yes, I have custom WebTemplate and yes, I have activated it. Project is very small, contains only webtemplate, masterpage and page. Any other tips? Anyone? Error message is just so odd and i'm not quite sure about Elements.xml, is it right.

Comment: Any help please? I'm stuck now.. Can anyone check solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, your download links are no longer available

Check the if Master Page is provisioned and set correctly. See sample `Elements.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="Masterpage" Url="_catalogs/masterpage">
    <File Path="Masterpage\Custom.master" Url="Custom.master" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="true" />
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

Check if the page layouts and welcome page being provisioned and set correctly also.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set a Homepge that does not exist? Does this homepage get created by any feature?

I'm assuming that if you go to `http://<your site>/_layouts/settings.aspx` you can actually see the settings.

Comment: That true, I can see the settings, however site throws 404. I re-uploaded 404 log file: https://mega.co.nz/#!Zh8BDDLC!NJOpODIwmeijILFuATRh21W-r6gjo11Zqb_hzn6wK4A

Here is full solution: https://mega.co.nz/#!VwMVgLYI!FZ1C3mZta0R6aNnSnEEKq2lCbBpng_yhJqt_6vhUr0c
I have still this problem but no solution =/

Comment: Is the homepage approved and have at least one major version published?

If you go to site Contents, you see your homepage anywhere ?

Comment: If I go "Site Contents", I cannot see my homepage... There is only "add an app" and "Style Library", which have 0 items.

Answer (score 0):

I found reason, why site throws 404! If I try deploy project and I have set Master Page scope = site, it will not work. Can anyone explain, why I have to deploy it scope = web?

I have set now Page & Master Page scope = web and WebTemplate scope = farm.